# How to store Monthly running services in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a university project which has a requirement to save the schedule of the different reports(Yearly,Monthly,Daily). These reports are run through windows service. I am thinking of creating a database table.

**Id----JobName-----DestinationFolder-----Startdate----Yearly---Monthly----Daily----LastRun**

I would appreciate if somebody could review the design.

Also is it a good idea to use a connected architecture here as that service will be running in the background and will check the date in database. If some report is scheduled to run at that time, then it will run.

Thanks!

Comment: I want to make the design more scale-able. If a user comes and says that he want to schedule a report that runs bi weekly, then i think this design will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one column to indicate how it's stored. Then select my `when stored_type = 'Monthly'`.

Or, to make it more relational, create another table where you have Stored types and use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule inner join type on schedule.stored_type_id=type.id 
WHERE type.id=1
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew . Actually I am not inclined towards making two tables, since running a join will only impact the efficiency.